# How do I make this generic sort in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to create a generic sort in Typescript. I want to sort any array alphabetically by a field name that I pass in to the function.

```
export const sortCollectionAlphabetically = <T, K extends keyof T>(
  collection: T[],
  key: K
): T[] => {
  return collection.sort((a, b) => {
    return a[key].localeCompare(b[key]);
  });
};
```

I have a collection of type `T`. I have a key value, `K`, that I want to guarantee is in type `T`. I also need the type system to know that type `T[K]` is going to be a string, so I can do the `localeCompare`. With my current code, it shows that `a[key]` is of type `T[K]`. How do I make the type system realize that it is a string? Obviously I do not want to cast any values.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N7GAPN) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer or find a relevant duplicate target; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes it does. Please submit an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Please see the linked q/a for details.